# Property Change event UWP not working

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

There have been a few questions regarding this issue and I have looked at a bunch of them, but I still seem to be getting something wrong!
All the examples on this forum that I have found is for one property and I sort of have a few / list.

In my Models folder I have a class called Locations

```
public class Locations: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    locationManager loc = new locationManager();



    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(List<String> PropertyChangedList)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Convert.ToString(PropertyChangedList)));
        }

    }

    public string locationColumn { get; set; }
    public int locationRow { get; set; }
    public string locationColumnImage { get; set; }
    public string baleInformation { get; set; }
    public int numberOfBales { get; set; }
    private List<String> columnList;
    public List<String> ColumnList
    {
        get
        {
            return columnList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != columnList)
            {
                columnList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(ColumnList);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

then in that same .cs file I have another class (yes not very good will still neaten it all out)

```
public class locationManager
{   

    #region GetLocations
    public  List<Locations> getLocations()
    {

        Locations storeLocations = new Locations();

        //represents db value of how many items in a particlar location
        var baleCol = buildColumnList();          
        var location = new List<Locations>();

        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "A", locationColumnImage = "Assets/A.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("A")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "B", locationColumnImage = "Assets/B.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("B")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "C", locationColumnImage = "Assets/c.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("C")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "D", locationColumnImage = "Assets/D.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("D")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "E", locationColumnImage = "Assets/E.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("E")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "F", locationColumnImage = "Assets/F.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("F")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "G", locationColumnImage = "Assets/G.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("G")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "H", locationColumnImage = "Assets/h.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("H")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "I", locationColumnImage = "Assets/I.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("I")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "J", locationColumnImage = "Assets/J.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("J")).Count() });
        location.Add(new Locations { locationColumn = "K", locationColumnImage = "Assets/K.jpg", numberOfBales = baleCol.Where(a => a != null && a.StartsWith("K")).Count() });
    return location;
    }
}
```

the `buildColumnList();` method that car baleCol equal to is just a method that creates a list of Letters/Bumber combos A1 or B15 type thing. this data will be pulled from the db at a later stage, so the method will be replaced with Linq.

In my `MainPage.xaml`, I have controls that I bind to in the following way

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind location, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="-5,0,5,0">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  x:Name="columnTemplate" x:DataType="data:Locations">
            <StackPanel x:Name="columnStack">
                <Image Width="100" Source="{x:Bind locationColumnImage}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize ="16" Text ="{x:Bind numberOfBales}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                    
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

and then the `MainPage.xaml.cs` has this

```
private List<Locations> location;
Locations baleLocations = new Locations();
locationManager manager = new locationManager();
int Count = 0; 
public MainPage()
{

    this.InitializeComponent();
    location = manager.getLocations();

}
```

So from what I have read I think my issue might be in the binding / Data Context. As in the MainPage.xaml I declare the gridview ItemSource as x:Bind location and then in the MainPage.xaml.cs I make location a list of type Locations (the class with the properties) I set this to a method in a different class LocationManager class' getLocations method

So on form load its all good I get the data I need, but what I am trying to achieve is to on find update the grid to only contain the items related to what I am wanting to find. so the grid then needs to update and that is where I am having problems. At this point the only thing that will change is the columnList property as I use that to get the A1, B15, C24

**Background:**

Its a storage facility that stores stock in row/column format so A1 B2 etc.. on initial load all possible Column locations are displayed with the number of items associated with that column regardless of row..
on Find if we are looking for  water only columns that has water in one of its rows should be in the grid... this is where the update / property change should happen.

Comment: You may also need an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a list.

Comment: " to on find update the grid to only contain the items related to what I am wanting to find." Did you mean update the gridview? Could you please tell  currently what the code snippet you are using for updating data? Where you are using the `columnList` property? If I don't understand you clearly please detail it.